# When I make a single jquery ajax post, firebug shows three distinct callbacks to the server

Tags: c#, jquery

Whenever I make an ajax callback in my current application, firebug shows three (always three) callbacks to the server, tow of which never seem to finish. I cannot even see what these two are passing, as expanding them shows nothing.

My code, executed on various activities, is as follows:

```
        $.post(Handler, coreParams, function (data) 
            {$(".PLTableTab").html(data); setAfterReload("pl", "perf");}, "html");
```

The handler and coreparames are nothing unusual - a handler location and the parameters to be passed in. This is stuff I have done in other places before, and never experienced this issue.

I have stepped through it, and there is just one call to this being made, which is generating the three server calls. I am only concerned, because this would appear to be slowing the application down over time.

I have googled this and checked stack overflow for other solutions, without success. It is not (any longer!) multiple bindings or the code being called at the wrong time.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the contents of `data`? Can it trigger the requests? Also what about the `setAfterReload`, is it possible that it triggers something that makes the requests?

Comment: ope - data is simple html and setafterReload does eventually trigger more requests. However, the three calls are all made simultaneously, before any of them have returned (i.e. before the setafterreload is called)

Comment: What is more, the failing calls are kicked off before the successful one. In case that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information on what events / methods call you $.post
Otherwise we can only guess the reason.

I found in most cases when jquery fires multiple times it is related to a class selector

```
$('.mytriggerclass').click(...
```

If you have errors in your html markup this could fire multiple times, e.g. in a menu with

tags if you miss a closing tag.

Comment: As I did say, it is just this one call to post that generates the multiple requests. It looks like it is trying multiple times, gettig rejected, and on hte third time (?why always the third?) getting through. But I don;t know why this could be.

Comment: It was a guess only, as I said without more code it's hard say what happens. You should show the complete script and the relevant html markup.